# Wrong font usage when exporting graphics with text

Tags: bugs, export, pdf-format, style, fonts

**Bug persists through 12.0**

---

When exporting graphics with annotation in PDF using `Export`, under some circumstances fonts are not inherited properly. I'll illustrate on the example of fonts containing subscripts, but the problem arises also when some other special characters are present (e.g. i've noticed it with "-" (minus) character as well)

This example illustrates expected behavior.

```
Graphics@Text[Subscript[ToString@x, ToString@1],BaseStyle -> FontFamily -> "Arial"]
Export["test1.pdf", %, "PDF"]
```

All characters in the "test1.pdf" file are printed using *Arial* font, which is expected behavior. However, when the `Subscript` construct is replaced with

```
Graphics@Text["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(1\)]\)",BaseStyle -> FontFamily -> "Arial"]    
Export["test2.pdf", %, "PDF"]
```

that is, when the input is entered in [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm.html), the exported file contains, besides *Arial* (subscript) also *CairoFont-0-0* (upper letter).
It seams that everything comes down to how `Export` interprets the underlying box structure. In the first case, the full form of the expression is

```
Graphics[Inset[Subscript["x", "1"], List[0, 0],Rule[BaseStyle, Rule[FontFamily, "Arial"]]]]
```

while in the second example, the underlying expression is

```
Graphics[Inset["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(1\)]\)",  
List[0, 0],Rule[BaseStyle, Rule[FontFamily, "Arial"]]]]
```

Since this is not limited to Subscript (i've noticed it also with `Plot` when the `Ticks` contains contains negative values), is this expected behavior or am I missing something?

P.S. 
Output of `$Version` is `"11.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (September 11, 2017)"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reproduced the issue with version 11.2.0 on Windows 7 x64.

The problem is that `Italic` text do not inherit `FontFamily` from the enclosing `Text` and even `Style`. Instead of this *Mathematica* generates and embeds in the PDF a new font `"CairoFont 0 0"` containing italicized version of the letter from the font specified via `FontFamily`:

```
$Version

Import[Export["test.pdf", 
    Style["text", Italic, FontFamily -> "Arial"]], 
   "TextOutlines" -> False][[1]] // InputForm
```

> ```
> "11.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (September 11, 2017)"
>
> Graphics[{Thickness[0.06],
>   Style[{Text["text", {0., 3.}, {Left, Baseline}]},
>    FontFamily -> "CairoFont 0 0", FontSize -> Scaled[0.58], Thickness[0.0625]]},
>  ImageSize -> {16., 12.}, PlotRange -> {{0., 16.}, {0., 12.}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
> ```

(note also the absence of `FontSlant -> "Italic"` in the first `Style` directive).

The problem does not exist in version 8.0.4:

```
$Version

Import[Export["test.pdf", 
    Style["text", Italic, FontFamily -> "Arial"]], 
   "TextOutlines" -> False][[1]] // InputForm
```

> ```
> "8.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (October 7, 2011)"
>
> Graphics[{Thickness[0.07],
>   Style[{Text["text", {0., 4.2}, {Left, Baseline}]}, 
>    FontFamily -> "Helvetica,", FontSlant -> "Italic", 
>    FontSize -> Scaled[0.6], Thickness[0.07]]}, 
>  ImageSize -> {15., 12.}, PlotRange -> {{0., 14.4}, {0., 12.}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
> ```

I recommend reporting this as an inconsistency or misbehavior. The expected behavior is what we got with version 8.0.4.

---

In the case of single letters when you don't need `Italic` one workaround is to switch off `SingleLetterItalics`:

```
Graphics@Text[Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(1\)]\)", FontFamily -> "Arial", 
    SingleLetterItalics -> False]];
Import[Export["test2.pdf", %, "PDF"], "TextOutlines" -> False][[1]] // InputForm
```

> ```
> Graphics[{Thickness[0.003], 
>   Style[{Text["x", {175.723145, 177.}, {Left, Baseline}]}, 
>    FontFamily -> "ArialMT",
>    FontSize -> Scaled[0.025], Thickness[0.003]],
>   Style[{Text["1", {180.223145, 175.5}, {Left, Baseline}]}, 
>    FontFamily -> "ArialMT", 
>    FontSize -> Scaled[0.017749022222222226], Thickness[0.003]]}, 
>  ImageSize -> {360., 360.}, 
>  PlotRange -> {{0., 360.}, {0., 360.}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
> ```

... or equivalently you can convert the letter into a string:

```
Graphics@Text[Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\"x\"\), \(1\)]\)", FontFamily -> "Arial"]];
Import[Export["test2.pdf", %, "PDF"], "TextOutlines" -> False][[1]] // InputForm
```

(output is identical).

Another way is to embed styling information directly into the string:

```
str = ToString[Style[Subscript[ToString@x, ToString@1], 
  FontFamily -> "Arial"], StandardForm];

Graphics[Text[str]]
Import[Export["test2.pdf", %, "PDF"], "TextOutlines" -> False][[1]] // InputForm
```

(output is identical).

But both workarounds don't solve the underlying problem of `Italic` text being exported with an artificial font instead of the font specified via the `FontFamily` option.

Comment: Ok, thank you for reproducing. If you know someone from Wolfram you can just mention him in the comments