# Cross platform PDF export. Consistent fonts in Windows vs. Linux

Tags: export, pdf-format, windows, linux

Here is an **example**:

```
nb = Notebook[
  {
   Cell[StringRiffle[Range[100], " "], "Text", FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 24]
  },
  PrintingOptions -> {    "PageSize" -> {595, 842},    "PaperSize" -> {595, 842}}
]

(* exports locally (WIN) and deploys to cloud for browser preview*)
SystemOpen@ First @ CloudExport[nb, "PDF", "temp/test-local.pdf"]

(* exports remotely (Cloud Unix) *)
SystemOpen @ First @ CloudEvaluate @ CloudExport[nb, "PDF", "temp/test-remote.pdf"]
```

[image]

[image]

Why isn't the output the same and how to make consistent PDF exports regardless of the operating system?

Comment: Not every viewer shows that but I found one that claims the remote versions uses `CairoFont` instead of `Arial`.

Comment: Which makes [156861](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/156861/5478) related but not solving my problem yet.

Comment: Not all fonts are same on windows and linux, even though they are called Arial on both., What happens if you use  “serif” or "sans-serif" instead? From what I understand, these are supposed to be best for cross platform.

Comment: @Nasser "Droid Serif" seems to work. But why not Arial?

Comment: @Nasser also, Arial is saved as CairoFont, not a 'different' Arial.